# How to add all values across pandas columns when the names of these columns match those in a list?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

```
list = ['abc', 'def_1', 'xyz_8']
```

An example row for a `df` below

```
abc_1     abc_99    def_1     def_2    xyz_8    xyz_1
2         1         1         2        2        3
```

I would like to scan and select only some of the `df` columns based on the list. The list element can be a substring of the column name. For example column `abc_1` will be included since `abc` is a substring, but `xyz_1` is not included since `xyz_1` is not an element of the list, and none of the list element is a substring of `xyz_1`.

I want a `df['sum']` = 6 (or 2+1+1+2) for that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) / [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

You can use `filter` or `str.contains`, both of which supports regex:

```
L = ['abc', 'def_1', 'xyz_8']

# courtesy of @JonClements
df['result'] = df.filter(regex='|'.join(L)).sum(1)

# original
df['result'] = df.iloc[:, df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(L))].sum(1)

print(df)

   abc_1  abc_99  def_1  def_2  xyz_8  xyz_1  result
0      2       1      1      2      2      3       6
```

Comment: Or maybe `df['result'] = df.filter(regex='|'.join(L)).sum(1)` ?

Comment: @JonClements, Yep, that in fact is better, thanks :) - though I'm not sure which is faster here

Comment: naively, I'd expect filter to always return a view, while `.iloc` may or may not return a copy (can never remember the rules of what has to copy and what doesn't... (pandas doesn't either - given all the warnings about "you're attemping to... ")... (bit too tired now to really look into it - that's just my initial thought (and most likely wrong one, but oh well))

Comment: understood the line for the most part, but what does the '1' in .sum() really mean?

Comment: @KubiK888, `axis=1` means sum across columns, [as described in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)